# C++ Create a Function that acts like a listener

Tags: c++, function, overriding

I don't know what to properly name this but is there a way to create a function on a separate thread that acts as a listener so that other functions can sort of attach to it in a way? Allowing that function to have its code executed in that listener.

```
void Listener::Run(){
   // create listener here
   // process whatever accesses this
}
```

then in another file and in a separate namespace/or class, we access this listener function and sort of override it so that we call that exact same function but implement our code so that it executes it asynchronously.

```
void Listener::Run(){
  //custom code that gets executed on actual listener function
}
```

Is this possible to do in C++ similar to how its done in Java?

Comment: Are you talking about inheritance and overriding `virtual` functions within a class?

Comment: This is often called "signals", if I understand the question correctly. They're not in standard C++, but several libraries implement them, such as boost.signals2.

Comment: @ChrisMM I assume so, I am going to update the post to give a better understanding. My apologies

Comment: @HolyBlackCat after reviewing some code of it, yes it does seem like what I want. I technically want said listener function to be an event handler that can be accessed in other namespaces/classes. However I can't work with boost so I'll have to find an alternative. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: There are several librares which implement that, it's a signal\slot architecture and is an application of subscriber\publisher pattern.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie ah ok, consider this question solved then. Thank you all, I will do my research from here.

Comment: A simple technique is to have a member `std::function<void()> m_callback` and a register function `template<typename fn_t> register(fn_t fn) { m_callback = fn; }`. Ofcourse you have to use the correct function signature for you callback, and then you can use a lamda expresion to register your callback function eg ; `register([]{ std::cout << "Hello World!";};` (in multithreaded applications you might want to make the register and invocation of the callback safe by using std::mutex/std::scoped_lock)

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie With one heads-up the most used mechanism is boost::signals2 and that is not threadsafe

Comment: @PepijnKramer GTK and libsigc++ born from bowels of GTK, also Qt and ActionScript are  good competition to that, and at least last two are partialy thread-safe (there is a probem of object's life-span as usual)

Comment: @PepijnKramer thank you for this, just one question. After I register do I just have the callback running in a while loop? Sorry if im incompetent

Comment: No the callback will have to be called on specific places in the code that something happens.  If you want to run something at regular intervals you need a poll loop not a callback, So next time also be clear in your question what you want to achieve (not only how you are solving something)

Comment: @PepijnKramer got it, gonna implement this right now. Thank you!

Comment: Might something like [libsigc++](https://libsigcplusplus.github.io/libsigcplusplus/) be what you are looking for?

Comment: @PepijnKramer are you sure not confusion boost.signals2 with boost.signals?

Comment: Nope signals2 is also not completely threadsade. Changing the number of registrations while it is calling back the registrations is the problen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can very well make some listening function to be run in a separate tread.  This is quite common for I/O and network listening.  In the context of internal listening between threads,  the listening is a little bit less straightforward, and the question too broad for an answer of reasonable length.  You could use for example:

- [`std::condition_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) in combination with a mutex to have some push-based listening. An alternative is the [`std::atomic_flag`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag_notify_all) family.
- periodic `std::this_thread::sleep_for` in combination with a queue querying at wake-up to have some pull-based mechanism.
- use some advanced lock-free input queue, to implement some message/signal passing.

What is not possible to do in a clean way however, is to replace on-the-fly a `Listener` object by a new object of a `Listener`-derived class overriding some methods. Some people will say that, yes you could destroy the object an create a new object in the same place, but to make this work is full of ambush and risks of UB.

The proper alternative to design this, is to run in a separate thread a listener object that uses a [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), i.e.  the actual listening, or processing of the incoming listening is done by another object (the strategy), and you'd then simply replace the strategy.  In a multithreaded context, you just make sure that to do the replacement in a harmless way, i.e. not destroying the object that is currently being used in the other thread (typically, you'd use some [mutexes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) for that).

I'd strongly recommend to read Antony William's book "*C++ concurrency in action*", which is fully dedicated to multi-threading programming, as multi-threading is quite tricky. Moreover, it may open your eyes to other approaches, that may be more effective than the listener-paradigm.